# Confused about GLSL and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So I am fairly new to OpenGL, and I have been experimenting around with GLSL, and of course, I have run into some problems. First of all, I should note that I am currently only drawing a singular triangle. Second, here are my (really simple) shaders:

```
// Vertex Shader

#version 330

in vec3 vertex_position;

void main() 
{
  gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
}
```

and

```
// Fragment Shader

#version 330

out vec4 fragColour;

void main() {
  fragColour = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This works well enough to draw a triangle. Great. Now I thought of editing the Vertex Shader such that instead of

```
gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0)
```

I do

```
gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 2.0)
```

and sure enough, it magnifies my triangle. So I thought, maybe if I take the Z from my vertex shader and set the W equal to it, I could get a sense of depth, so I did this:

```
// Vertex Shader

#version 330

in vec3 vertex_position;

void main() 
{
  gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, vertex_position.z);
}
```

but alas, when I run the program, it shows nothing. In case people are wondering, here are my vertices:

```
float points[] = {
   0.0f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f
};
```

Also, I should say that I noticed that changing the z value in `float points[]` to anything other than 0 makes that part of the triangle invisible for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "vertex" whose `w` coordinate is 0 is considered to be infinitely far, so it won't be displayed. `w` of 0 is used to represent directions, not points.

Setting `w` equal to `z` will *remove* any sense of depth. The actual 3D coordinates of a point `[x, y, z, w]` are `[ x/w, y/w, z/w ]` (that's the principle of homogenous coordinates).

Normally, you keep `w` fixed at 1.0, and set the vertex position via `x`, `y` and `z`.

Comment: Okay, then if I edit `float points[]`'s Z's to 1, it should set W = 1, but this still doesn't show anything. Isn't `vertex_position.z` supposed to get the given vertex's Z value? And if that Z value is 1, then my code should automatically set W to 1?

Comment: @Nooble: Well, Z=1 in NDC coordinates you're pushing the vertex out of the clip space, so all your vertices get clipped. You should read up on how to do transforms properly. I.e. building a model and a projection matrix and hwo those work.

Comment: @Angew I do know how to use matrices,  I was just curious about this. Any number _at_ _all_ besides zero seems to push it out of Clip Space. For example, 0.5, which is well in between -1 to 1. Speaking of -1 to 1, is it inclusive?

Comment: @Nooble Look at how you have written your vertex program: Zh = Z and W = Z. Then at perspective divide stage, when the homogenous coordinates are transformed to cartesian coordinates, z = Zh/W = Z/Z = 1. So you got it clipped and see nothing.